# Can't serialize request.data with another function inside post method.using Post request. DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Django and DRF.
I have a **Model** with Image and ForeignKey fields.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=False)
    predicted_result = models.ForeignKey(PredictedIllness, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializer**:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields =['image','predicted_result']
```

And a **view**:

```
class UploadImage(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = ImageSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response('Classified', status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def classify_image(self, image_file, image):
        image = open_image(image)
        pred_class, pred_idx, outputs = fastAi_learner.predict(image)
        print(pred_class.data.item())
        return pred_class.data.item()
```

So when I'm shooting with the POST request, everything works fine and Response: 'Classified' withStatus 201 is returned.

But, what I want to do is to classify image myself, using classify_image function.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    try:
        im = pilImage.open(request.data['image'])
        if im.load():
            predicted_condition = self.classify_image(image_file=request.data['image'].name,
                                                      image=request.data['image'])
            request.data['predicted_result'] = predicted_condition
            serializer = ImageSerializer(data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(1, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except IOError:
        return Response('problems with image', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

For Some reason, When I'm shooting from Postman with exactly the same request I receive the following 400 Response:

```
{
    "image": [
        "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."
    ]
}
```

What can cause this error is thrown? Because I send exactly the same image. And how can I add custom data(not from request) to serializer itself/request correctly?